# vhdl functions/procedures constant arguments

Tags: c, arguments, constants, vhdl

One can label arguments to a function or procedure with the keyword constant e.g.

```
function prefix_len(constant n: integer; 
                    constant pospre: positive_prefix) return natural;
```

Using the const keyword in C is essential because you get a warning if you pass a constant to a functioning expecting non constant which is the default. And arguments, strings in particular are often const.

However I fail to see the point of constant in VHDL. Although the function above does indeed expect both arguments to be constant and will not and cannot attempt to modify the arguments.

With procedure you declare a direction and making an inout or out argument constant would be contradictory, and the compiler does complain. But once again you have the option of declaring the in arguments to be constant.

```
procedure lprintf(outl: inout line; 
                  constant format: in string; 
                  constant a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t: in string := NONE_STRING);
```

So are the constant declarations above good practice or a waste of characters?

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 4.2.2.1 Formal parameter lists "For those parameters with modes, the only modes that are allowed for formal parameters of a procedure are **in**, **inout**, and **out**. If the mode is **in** and no object class is explicitly specified, **constant** is assumed. If the mode is **inout** or **out**, and no object class is explicitly specified, **variable** is assumed."

Comment: "In a subprogram call, the actual designator (see 6.5.7.1) associated with a formal parameter of class **signal** shall be a name denoting a signal. The actual designator associated with a formal of class **variable** shall be a name denoting a variable. The actual designator associated with a formal of class **constant** shall be an expression. The actual designator associated with a formal of class **file** shall be a name denoting a file."

Comment: Yep I was aware that files have no direction. Whereas lines are inout. Not clear why files behave differently to lines.    


`procedure fprintf(file outf: text; constant format: in string; constant a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t: in string := NONE_STRING);`

Comment: In VHDL subprograms have parameters not arguments. Look for similarities with programming languages not superimposition of concepts. VHDL is formally defined and almost self contained.  5.5 File types, 5.5.1 "File types are used to define objects representing files in the host system environment. The value of a file object is the sequence of values contained in the host system file." 16.4 Package TEXTIO "`type LINE is access STRING;`". A line is a pointer to a string value.

Comment: a line is only inout because the line pointer/value may change during the call. Its perfectly legal to have a line type (or any access type) as a variable in or out from a procedure. An access type can also be returned from a function.

Comment: It's obvious why a line is inout. It must be read, and will be modified if the line is written to. It's just not clear why the file has no direction. Is a file a fundamental type like integer instead of derived like character or unsigned?

Comment: A file is a class of an object, not a type like integer. VHDL does not define how files are handled it is left up to the tool. With VHDL 2008 and prior, files can only be opened, closed, read or written with no seeking or rewinding, and only in the type they were opened with. There is no binary file IO. A line type is just a pointer to a string. A line does not have to be inout from a procedure. It can legitimately be in or out (but must always be a variable because it is an access type).

Answer (score 2):

In VHDL, the class of a parameter affects what you can connect it to. Also, the default class depends on the mode. For subprogram paramters:

Paramters of mode in default to constant. When calling the subprogram, any signal, variable or constant can be connected to a constant parameter. Parameters without a mode default to in, and paramters of mode in default to constant.

Paramters of mode out or inout default to variable. Only variables can be connected to variables.
A parameter of mode out labelled as constant would only connect to constants.

Anything labelled as a signal can only be connected to a signal.

files can only be connected to files, and files are not allowed a mode.

So in your examples, constant is not explicitly needed as it would have been the class of the the inputs by default.

So in most cases, constant is not needed explicitly. But it can help with clarity when you have a subprogram with a lot of paramters with a mix of classes and modes. It can make it clearer for the reader what can be conneted to what.

Comment: Ok so the bottom line is constant (in argument definitions) only serves to make what is implicit explicit. It's purely syntactic sugar and can really just be considered as a comment?

Comment: No. Tricky's dropped vowels aside there are restrictions on combinations of class and mode that do the same thing you referred to in C with `const`.

Comment: class!!! If there's a class statement in VHDL that passed me by. Especially as conceptually I feel entity are like classes processes like methods, and functions/procedures a convenience rather than a necessary part of the language.

Comment: Every object has a class, like signal, variable, constant or file. VHDL has no object orientation. Protected types are probably the closest thing to it.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.4 Objects, 6.4.1 General "There are four classes of objects: constants, signals, variables, and files. The variable class of objects also has an additional subclass: shared variables. The class of an explicitly declared object is specified by the reserved word that shall or may appear at the beginning of the declaration of that object. For a given object of a composite type, each subelement of that object is itself an object of the same class and subclass, if any, as the given object. The value of a composite object is the aggregation of the values of its subelements."

Comment: There are four classes of objects: constants, signals, variables, and files. Aha that one sentence brings lots of clarity. Except class is such an overused word in prgramming.